# Pop-ups are not working on hover or mouse click

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers

I am trying to display popups for open layers as shown LAYER1, I want to display that when user hovers over a particular polygon of the layer it displays fields information from attribute table which are Name and Area. There is no error and no feature is returned in console as well.Please suggest me solution for this.

**Javascript:**

```
//Layers for which popups have to be displayed
var LAYERNAME = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Workspace/wms',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'Workspace:LAYERNAME', 'TILED': false },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
        transition: 0
    }),
    visible:false,
    title: 'LAYER1'
})

var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [75,31],
    zoom: 8.5,
    // minZoom: 14,
})
var map = new ol.Map({

    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: false
        }
    }).extend([
        new app.drawFeatures(), new app.deleteFeatures()
    ]),

    overlays: [overlay],
    target: 'map',
    view: view,
    layers: [basemap, LAYERNAME],
    
    //Overlay container for layer
    var OverlayElement=document.querySelector('.overlay-container');
    var Overlay=new ol.Overlay({
        element: OverlayElement,
        positioning: 'center-left'
    })
    
    map.addOverlay(Overlay);

    //POPUP using fiels name from attribute table
    const Name=document.getElementById('Name');
    const Area=document.getElementById('Area');
    
    map.on('click',function(e){
        Overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        //var info = [];
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function(feature,layer){
            //info.push(feature.get('Name'));
            const coordinate=e.coordinate;
            var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(new ol.proj.toLonLat(coordinate));
            content.innerHTML = '<p>You clicked here:</p><code>' + coordinate + '</code>';
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
            console.log(e.coordinate);
            let clickedFeatureName=feature.get('Name');
            let clickedFeatureArea=feature.get('Area');
    
            Overlay.setPosition(ClickedCoordinate);
            Name.innerHTML="Name:"+clickedFeatureName;
            Area.innerHTML="Area:"+clickedFeatureArea;
    
        }),
    })
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="grid-1">
         <div id='map' class='map'></div>
         <div id="popup" style='width:180px' class="ol-popup">
              <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
              <div id="popup-content"></div>
         </div>
         </div>
    </div>
         <div class="overlay-container">
            <span class='Overlay-text' id='Name'></span><br>
            <span class='Overlay-text' id='Area'></span><br>
         </div>
```